# 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed || groupby().apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a trouble with pandas, Below is code:

```
print(right_df)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLXYF.png)

```
print(right_top)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjVGw.png)

```
g = right_df.groupby('exam_id').apply(right_top)
print(g)
```

The error is "TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"
how can i solve it??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a *function* to the `apply(...)`.
In your code, you pass a *DataFrame*, hence, pandas try to call the dataframe (`__call__` method of the object pandas.DataFrame) and hence the error.

See explanation on *apply* [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

In order to help you with the specific problem, please provide more information on your intent.